# calling main function in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point

```
#define f(x) (x*(x+1)*(2*x+1))/6
void terminate();
main()
{
   int n,op;
   char c;
   printf("Enter n value\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   op=f(n);
   printf("%d",op);
   printf("want to enter another value: (y / n)?\n");
   scanf("%c",&c);   // execution stops here itself without taking input.
   getch();
   if(c=='y')
    main();
   else
    terminate();
   getch();

 }
void terminate()
{
exit(1);
}
```

In the program above , I want to take input from the user until he enters an `n` value. 
For this I'm trying to call `main()` function repeatedly . If it is legal in C , I want to know why the program terminates at the `scanf("%c",&c)` as shown in commented line.
Someone , please help.

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least. And assuming `terminate()` is not meant to take any parameters, it should be `void terminate(void)`.

Comment: @alk - made the changes , still the problem persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never call `main` from within your program. If you need to run it more then once use a `while` loop inside it.

Your execution stops because by default stdin in a terminal is line buffered. Also you are not using the return value from `getch`.

```
int main()
{
   int n,op;

    char c;
    do {
        printf("Enter n value\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        op=f(n);
        printf("%d",op);
        printf("want to enter another value: (y / n)?\n");
        scanf("%c",&c);
    } while (c == 'y')

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `getch` call is to get and discard the newline left by the `scanf` call in the buffer. Which is not needed in this case (as you show in your code snippet).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg He is only calling `scanf` which by default discards all whitespace characters. No need for that.

Comment: Not when scanning for a character.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah. The next `scanf` call scans for an integer though, so it's fine. I would have used `fgets` and then `sscanf` from buffer though.

Answer (score 3):

You first have

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

which you have to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for it to accept the number.

Later you have

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

There is a problem here, which is that the first call to `scanf` leaves that <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the input buffer. So the later `scanf` call will read that.

This is easily solved, by changing the format string for the second `scanf` call just a little bit:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
/*     ^           */
/*     |           */
/* Note space here */
```

This tells the `scanf` function to skip leading *whitespace*, which includes newlines like the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key leaves.

Comment: @haccks It's my avatar yes, not animated though. :) Got it as a reward for a [Kickstarter pledge](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/168734274/sam-and-fuzzy-two-volume-omnibus). :)

Comment: In fact its very much looks like you (as I seen in your old avatar) and that's why I asked you. :)

Comment: @haccks Yeah, the artist really "caught me" :)

Answer (score 1):

It's legal, but you'll have a STACKOVERFLOW after a while (pun intended).
What you need is a loop:

```
while (1) {
  printf("Enter n value\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  op=f(n);
  printf("%d",op);
  printf("want to enter another value: (y / n)?\n");
  scanf("%c",&c);   // execution stops here itself without taking input.
  getch();
  if(c != 'y')
    break;;
}
```